# How to bind a field in __init__ function of a form

Tags: python, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

```
class Example_Form(Form):
    field_1 = TextAreaField()
    field_2 = TextAreaField()

    def __init__(self, type, **kwargs):
        super(Example_Form, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        if type == 'type_1':
           self.field_3 = TextAreaField()
```

In some scenarios I need to dynamically add fields into the form. The field_3 added to example form turns out to be a UnboundField. I tried to bind field_3 to form in `__init__` function, but it won't work.

```
field_3 = TextAreaField()
field_3.bind(self, 'field_3')
```

How to bind field_3 to example form?

Comment: Do you perhaps want a subclass of `Example_Form` for this specific case? The fields are class declarations, not instance attributes, the difference is important for the descriptor protocol and other metaprogramming techniques `WTForms` is likely using.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `self.meta.bind_field` to create a bound field, and assign it to the instance and the `_fields` dict.

```
self.field_3 = self._fields['field_3'] = self.meta.bind_field(
    self, TextAreaField(),
    {'name': 'field_3', 'prefix': self._prefix}
)
```

---

In most cases, it's more clear to use a subclass and decide which class to use when creating the form instance.

```
class F1(Form):
    x = StringField()

class F2(F1):
    y = StringField()

form = F1() if type == 1 else F2()
```

If you need to be more dynamic, you can subclass the form and assign fields to it. Assigning fields to classes works directly, unlike with instances.

```
class F3(F1):
    pass

if type == 3:
    F3.z = StringField()

form = F3()
```

You can also define all fields, then choose to delete some before validating the form.

```
class F(Form):
    x = StringField()
    y = StringField()

form = F()

if type == 1:
    del form.y
```