# WTForms dynamic field: binding a unbounded field with bind()

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

I have looked into the bind() function/method of wtforms in combintation with python3 flask and jinja.
My goal is to make on the fly a hiddenfield which is included in the base model on render time in the form. I have spend days looking for a solution but it is not clear to me. How does binding a unbound field work?

A little snippet of things i tried

```
# self.model.append_field(
    name="multiselector_results", 
    field=HiddenField()
    )
tmp = HiddenField(
    label="multiselector_results", 
    validators=[], 
    description="", 
    id="multiselector_results", 
    default=""
    )

tmp.bind(
    self.model, 
    "multiselector_results"
    )

# self.model.multiselector_results.bind(self, tmp)

# self.model._fields["multiselector_results"] = self.model.multiselector_results.bind(
    self, HiddenField(), {"name": "multiselector_results"})
# self.model.multiselector_results.bind()
```

My main Form class includes this function

```
@classmethod
def append_field(cls, name, field):
    setattr(cls, name, field)
    return cls
```

The `append_field` function is in a main class called `Form` where every model basically inhirits from.
I am able to assign the hidden field to my model on the fly which validates the `append_field` method is actually working, but the hidden field itself stays Unbound for some reason.
The documentation is not clear enough for me since even `ctrl` + `F` brings up one hit with `bind()`.

Here a couple of references I have looked into:

```
http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/0.6/fields.html
https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/forms.html#wtforms.form.Form.__init
https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/wtforms/2.0.2/wtforms.pdf
https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/wtforms/1.0.5/wtforms.pdf
http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/1.0.2/fields.html
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/wtforms/cJl3aqzZieA
```

I also found a couple of stack overflow question which are scary close to this one, however slightly different. Those solutions however gave me new inspiration to try stuff out. A example topic:

[How to bind a field in __init__ function of a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43267820/how-to-bind-a-field-in-init-function-of-a-form)

I do like the other solutions `davidism` provided but its out of the question in my case.

Only thing in the whole wtforms documentation which i have found about `bind()`

```
If _form and _name isn’t provided, an UnboundField will be returned instead. Call its 
bind() method with a form instance and a name to construct the field.
```

How can a unbound field get constructed?